# how we can use split function with multiple _

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

```
data = ['test_function']
```

If we want to split `'test_function'` we use following command (what is learn)

```
test = data['test_function'].str.split('_', expand = True)
```

then it will create two row 'test' and 'function'

what if

```
data = ['test_function_practice']
```

and we only want to separate only 'test' and 'function' how we can do this

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `n` to change the limit for the number of splits.

try:

```
test = data['test_function'].str.split('_', n = 1, expand = True)
```

**output:**

```
      0                  1
0  test  function_practice
```